# Why mktime() returns negative integer for year > 2039

Tags: php

Why `mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2040)` returns negative integer `-2054446096` ?
Is it not supposed to return the number of secs since 01.01.1970 meaning 64-bit positive integer?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: There is vague note `Times beyond 03:14:07 UTC on Tuesday, 19 January 2038 will 'wrap around' and be stored internally as a negative number`. However that does not explain why it must be negative and not positive integer if I run 64-bit PHP.

Comment: Then it's not clear what your question is, because the linked duplicate and Wikipedia article explain it **exactly**. Is your question actually "why does signed integer overflow produce a negative value"? That's a very different question than the one you've asked. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow.

Comment: But there is no overflow on 64-bit platforms ..

Comment: Using a 64 bit platform does not guarantee you are using a PHP compiled to use 64 bit `time_t`.

Comment: Regarding the negative number you've got in the result, it's because after `2038-1-19 03:14:07 UTC`, the 32-bit signed integer used for timestamp representation will overflow and become -2^31 (-2147483648) and it will start adding seconds to that negative number trying to get the equivalent timestamp for `2040-31-12 00:00:00 UTC` which doesn't exist. The timestamp  (-2054446096) is actually for the date time `1904-11-24 16:31:44 UTC`